# Find a basis for polynomial vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Q: Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field, $U=\{p\in P_4(\mathbb{F}):p(6)=0\}$ , find a basis for $U$,Extend the basis to a basis for $P_4(\mathbb{F})$ and find a subspace $W$ of $P_4(\mathbb{F})$, such that $W \oplus U=P_4(\mathbb{F})$.

My solution is really short and seems easy, I'm not sure if I'm missing something.

I'm thinking the set $ B:=\{z-6,(z-6)^2,(z-6)^3,(z-6)^4\}$ as the basis for $U$, and to extend that to a basis for $P_4(\mathbb{F})$, I can just adjoin $1$ to the set. Which in this case, let $W=\mathbb{F}$ and $\mathbb{F}\oplus U=P_4(\mathbb{F})$.

$B$ is linearly independent, note $a_0(z-6)+a_1(z-6)^2+a_2(z-6)^3+a_3(z-6)^4=0$ iff $a_1=a_2=a_3=a_4=0$ since each of the terms are of different degrees.

To show that $span(B)=U$, let $u\in span(B)$, then $u(6)=0$ which implies $u \in U$. conversely, $u(6)=a_0+a_16+a_26^2+a_36^3+a_46^4=0$, and this doesn't seem like an element of $span (B)$.

Comment: A side question... What is $\mathbb F$ here?

Comment: Your solution is indeed short. The issue is that depending on what was asked to you, your solution is lacking some proof. Why is $B$ a basis? Why is $W \oplus U = P_4(\mathbb F)$?

Comment: Thanks, $\mathbb{F}$ is field for $P_4(\mathbb{F})$. I think I will have to prove B is Linearly independent and spans U.

Comment: Yes you have to prove that. And $6$ could be equal to zero. For example in $\mathbb F_3$.